# Imparfait vs. passé composé for “devoir”?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, passé-composé, auxiliaires, imparfait

I'm completely clear on the different uses of the two tenses, except for pretty much this one verb.

Can I get some different examples, with translations, of when you would say *Il devait* as opposed to *Il a dû* ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't really understand what bothers you, the uses of these tenses are the same as for all verbs, except that as a semi-auxiliary, the semantic information is transferred to the verb it modifies, but it is the same as for any other semi-auxiliary, e.g. *vouloir* or *pouvoir*.

- *devait* is the past imperfective (or *inaccompli*) for situational information, it denotes that in the frame of the sentence, the subject had an obligation, without specifying if he complied to it

  > *Il devait partir à Rome et sa femme voulait venir.*
  >   *Il devait cuisiner l'*​osso bucco *mais il a oublié.*
- *a dû* is the past perfective (*accompli*), it denotes that the subject *did* the thing he had to do:

  > *Il a dû partir à Rome précipitamment.*
  >   *Comme il ne restait plus que de la viande hachée, il a dû faire une bolognaise à la place.*

So *devait* denotes a **context**, whereas *a dû* denotes an **action**. Thus, *a dû* implies that the action has been done whereas *devait* does not, but it is more a side-effect than the real point of this choice of tense.

Comment: Haha sorry Evpok this didn't help me at all. You gave me sentences using each in French, but since there's no translation, I don't understand the difference between those sentences. They seem the same to me. "He had to leave for  Rome and his wife wanted to come." "He had to leave for Rome immediately."

Comment: Let me know if my edit is accurate, you made a misleading typo. The answer makes more sense now but could still use a little expansion. Is the difference that straightforward: past perfective means they actually did what they had to do, whereas imparfait leaves the conclusion uncertain?

Comment: @Aerovistae well I don't know if this nuance *can* be translated in English. You are right: *devait* does leave the conclusion incertain, but it is more a side-effect than the actual difference.

Comment: You could maybe translate *devait faire* with *had to do*, thus uncertain about the outcome of the action, and *a dû* with *did*, thus certain that the action actually took place. Example: *He had to leave but stayed an extra day. He left but had to stay an extra day.*

Comment: @Evpok By the way, the final edit to this answer made it incredibly clear-- this makes a lot of sense now. Had no idea that distinction existed.

Comment: What about the past perfective meaning a supposition: *Il est en retard. Il a dû tomber en panne d'essence*. It's the opposite of the certitude *he had to*.

Answer (score 6):

When *devoir* is given an “accomplished aspect” using *passé composé* (or any other composed tense), it expresses “fulfilment” of a necessity. By the course of events, something just ceased to be necessity. It means that the person did what he had to do, and *strangely* (I concede) it cannot mean that the problem solved by itself (this is pretty much specific to *devoir* and a few other modal-like verbs).

For example, “*il a dû se présenter devant le juge*” means he had to *and did* appear before the judge. If  the problem solved externally, one would use *imparfait*, or provide an explicit reason introduced, for example, as follows:

> Il a *cru* devoir se présenter devant le juge, jusqu'à l'arrivée d'un nouveau temoin.

This is possible because *croire* (similarly *vouloir*) relate the subject's thoughts or wills, which are expected to adapt to the course of external events. Verbs like *devoir* or *pouvoir* or *savoir* are different because the subject isn't taking any action or position or decision and is just passive. I'd say this is what makes them special. In particular, similar to “*il a dû*”, the sentence “*il a pu/su faire quelque chose*” also means that he could/knew how to do it *and did it*.

---

Note: it can get even more confusing since *devoir* may also express likeliness, not only necessity (and *pouvoir* may also express possibility).

> — Tu sais pourquoi Pierre n'est pas là ?
>   — Il *doit* être occupé… ou il *a dû* partir à Rome !

In this context you can forget all the above, as the reply is just a guess about the reasons (English would use *must*: “he must be busy… or he must have left for Rome”.)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to avoid some of the ambiguity in the translation would be to say "He was supposed to leave for Rome..." for "Il devait partir à Rome..." That way the "He had to leave for Rome immediately" can be definitive.