# Falloir : pourquoi l'imparfait et non pas le passé composé ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

L'extrait ci-dessous est tiré de la p. 88 de *Advanced French Grammar* par V. Mazet. J'ai déjà consulté [Imparfait vs. passé composé for devoir?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6249/imparfait-vs-passe-compose-for-devoir/6287#6287).

> Il **fallait** t'arrêter au carrefour même si tu n'avais pas vu de stop. = You needed to stop at the intersection even if you had not seen a stop sign.

Ici, on ne fait allusion qu'à un carrefour. La phrase insinue résolument et sans doute que le conducteur ne s'y est pas arrêté (j'emploie le PC ici).

Ainsi, le verbe **falloir**, pourquoi a-t-il été conjugué à l'imparfait ? Je pense que je comprends les bases sur le passé composé vs l'imparfait.

---

**Un supplément :**

> Pourquoi : Il **a fallu** t'arrêter au carrefour même si tu n'avais pas vu de stop. ≠ La personne **a dû** s'arrêter au carrefour. ?

Comment: "Il a fallu t'arrêter au carrefour", avec le passé composé, est également grammatical, mais avec un sens différent : "Il a fallu qu'on t'arrête au carrefour." ("You had to be stopped at the intersection")

Comment: Merci de votre commentaire. SVP, pourriez-vous vous attarder sur la raison pourquoi **Il a fallu qu'on t'arrête au carrefour = "You had to be stopped at the intersection"** en tant qu'une réponse dessous ?

Comment: @a3nm C'est incorrect: les deux sens sont possibles elon ce que le verbe est employé avec un pronom réfléchi ou pas (mais la confusion ne se produirait presque jamais en contexte).

Comment: Circeus: Je suis d'accord qu'avec "fallait" les deux sens sont possibles selon le contexte, mais avec le passé composé je ne vois aucune manière d'interpréter "il a fallu t'arrêter" comme une construction pronominale et j'aurais tendance à dire qu'il faudrait impérativement reformuler, par exemple : "Il a fallu que tu t'arrêtes au carrefour."

Comment: @a3nm j'ai noté que le sens d'arrestation semble plus plausible, mais l'original est quand même valide, mais si ce n'est pas la manière la plus naturelle de le dire (y compris pour moi, qui préfère généralement *devoir* aux temps autre que le présent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je crois que c'est une bizarrerie sémantique liée au sens du verbe lui-même (mais je serais bien en mal d'expliquer plus en détail) qui force l'imparfait dans ce cas.

En effet, si la phrase était *il a fallu t'arrêter au carrefour*, cela voudrait dire, à l'inverse, que la personne **s'est arrêtée (ou a été arrêtée)** au carrefour et étant donné la suite de la phrase, on obtient alors un non-sens évident... L'imparfait a ici (grosso modo) le même sens que le subjonctif ou conditionnel passé: "Il aurait fallu t'arrêter".

**Ajouts**

**Concernant le sens opposé du passé composé:** cette opposition est due à la même opposition de sens que j'ai décrite dans [votre autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6726/quand-utiliser-le-passe-compose-ou-limparfait-pour-decrire-une-journee). L'imparfait ici transcrit un état: à ce moment là, il fallait arrêter, mais ne transmet aucune information quant à savoir si cet arrêt a été effectué. Par contre, le passé composé établit un fait précis, soit qu'il y a eu arrêt, et qu'il était donc présumablement inévitable pour une raison ou une autre (si la phrase était *Il m'a fallu/me fallait arrêter parce que j'avais un pneu crevé*, les deux conjugaisons seraient possibles avec à peu près le même sens).

**Concernant les deux sens possibles de *arrêter*:** c'est parce que *arrêter* peut avoir un sens transitif (celui où il y a une arrestation) et un sens réfléchi (celui où il y a un arrêt). Je n'ai mentionné cette autre possibilité que parce que la phrase *Il a fallu t'arrêter* a plus de chances d'être employée dans le contexte d'une arrestation policière (mais par pitié ne me demandez pas pourquoi, ça deviendrait ridiculement difficile à expliquer, et mes connaissances en syntaxe sémantique ne sont certainement pas assez avancées!).

Comment: Merci. Pourriez-vous détailler pourquoi **Il a fallu t'arrêter au carrefour.** = **La personne s'est arrêtée (ou a été arrêtée) au carrefour.** ≠ *La personne a dû s'arrêter au carrefour.* ?

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour vos ajouts. Dans votre phrase « Par contre, le passé composé établi un fait précis, soit qu'il y a eu arrêt, et qu'**il** était ...», quel est l'antécédent du pronom **il** ?

Comment: L'antécédent est *arrêt*.

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant.

Answer (score 1):

Tout simplement par qu'il s'agit d'un événement qui appartient uniquement au passé.
Le passé composé sous-entend (même si c'est un peu restreint comme définition) une incidence dans le présent.

```
J'ai perdu mes clefs : dans le sens où maintenant je ne peux pas ouvrir la porte

J'ai appris ma leçon : dans le sens où je la sais maintenant

j'apprenais mes leçons quand j'était petit : tout cela est dans le passé, pas de conséquence dans le présent

Il fallait t'arrêter au stop : c'est passé, maintenant c'est trop tard, on ne peut plus s'arrêter.

-Pourquoi êtes-vous en retard ? - Nous nous sommes trompés de chemin alors il a fallu repartir en arrière : l'incidence présente est le retard (sujet de la conversion)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Il faut t'arrêter ... tu as vu
>  Il fallait t'arrêter ... tu avais
>   vu

La perception de la vue est faite, elle demande/impose une réaction à venir.
On constate son absence par la suite.

> Il faut t'arrêter ... tu vois 
>   Il fallait t'arrêter ... tu voyais

Ici, l’événement perçu est contemporain à l'obligation de réagir.
Il est encore possible d'agir au moment de l'énoncé de la phrase

---

*Suite au commentaire se Shlublu : "...*

> Il fallait t'arrêter ... tu as vu

*... par exemple, si l'on est passager d'une voiture dont le conducteur a grillé un feu, lorsque le sifflet du gendarme retentit."* :

Dans ce cas, l'injonction induite du verbe *falloir* est renforcée, la faute aggravée : il n'y a plus d'espace ni de temps entre l'événement constaté et sa formulation, le présent est nécessaire pour signaler ce constat fait "sur le champ".

Comment: On dit "Il fallait t'arrêter, tu as vu !" pourtant. Par exemple, si l'on est passager d'une voiture dont le conducteur a grillé un feu, lorsque le sifflet du gendarme retentit.

Answer (score 1):

> Pourquoi : Il **a fallu t'arrêter** au carrefour même si tu n'avais pas vu
>   de stop. **≠** La personne **a dû s'arrêter** au carrefour. ?

La première phrase n'est pas correcte du point de vue de la conjugaison, la proposition principale devrait être au conditionnel passé deuxième forme :

> Il **aurait fallu t'arrêter** ...

auquel cas on peut écrire une équivalence avec :

> La personne **aurait dû s'arrêter** ...

Si on emploie la proposition principale seule, on peut effectivement dire

> Il **a fallu t'arrêter** au carrefour

qui peut être équivalente à :

> Quelqu'un ou quelque chose **t'a arrêté** au carrefour.