# Pour décrire une journée : le passé composé ou l'imparfait ?

Tags: temps-grammatical, passé-composé, imparfait

La page 33 dans *Advanced French Grammar* de V. Mazet prétend ceci :

> The passé composé is used for naming, as opposed to describing, actions that happened within a defined period of time. The key word here is WITHIN. You are considering the period of time as a sealed time capsule, and it doesn't matter how long the period was, as long as it's finite in the mind of the speaker.
>
> **1.** Aujourd'hui il fait beau, mais hier il **a plu**.

La page 37 prétend :

> Think of the imparfait as the past tense of calm, beauty, and thought: it paints portraits and scenes, thoughts and memories; it does not busy itself with actions.
>
> **2.** Le jour où elle s'est mariée, elle **était** radieuse.

J'ai du mal à comprendre la phrase n<sup>o</sup> 2. Pourquoi n'est-ce pas plutôt :

> **3.** Le jour où elle s'est mariée, elle **a été** radieuse ?

Dans la phrase 1, « pleuvoir » est au passé composé car on ne parle que du lendemain. Dans la phrase 2, on ne parle que de jour du mariage qui est par le passé. Ainsi, c'est une « capsule temporelle scellée », ainsi que le disait le livre.

J'ai déja consulté [Falloir : pourquoi l'imparfait et non pas le passé composé ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6712/falloir-pourquoi-limparfait-et-non-pas-le-passe-compose).

Comment: La première phrase semble bizarre. J'utiliserai l'imparfait dans ce cas car je trouve qu'il s'agit plus de « thoughts and memories » que de « actions ». À mon avis, ça serait une action si on disait p.ex. « Aujourd'hui il fait beau *car* hier il a plu. »

Answer (score 4):

La phrase :

> Le jour où elle s'est mariée, elle était radieuse.

contient une notion de durée, elle était radieuse [*toute la journée*].

Alors qu'avec le passé composé :

> Le jour où elle s'est mariée, elle a été radieuse

ne contient pas cette notion de durée, elle a été radieuse [*pendant un bref instant au cours de cette journée*].

Answer (score 4):

Je crois que Mazet ne parvient pas très bien à décrire deux usages légèrement distincts de l'imparfait:

1. Indiquer une action qui s'étend dans le temps (et fréquemment est « interrompue » par une action ponctuelle précise): *Elle était heureuse quand elle s'est mariée*. D'ailleurs l'action n'a pas besoin de s'étendre très longtemps dès lors qu'elle est contrastée de cette façon: *Il allait partir, mais je l'en ai empêché*.
2. Établir une description (particulièrement dans un contexte de narration). En effet, c'est l'imparfait qui s'emploie pour faire la description au passé, et c'est plus particulièrement cet usage auquel la p. 37 fait référence.

Par ailleurs, *Hier il a plu* et *Hier, il pleuvait* n'ont pas tout à fait le même sens, ou plutôt les mêmes allusions. *Il a plu* est un état binaire opposé à *Il n'a pas plu de la journée* (*il ne pleuvait pas*, étant « descriptif », requiert un contexte un peu plus large, explicite ou implicite), et notamment peut s'employer pour une courte averse, alors que *hier il pleuvait*, implique au contraire qu'il a plu toute la journée, ou presque.

Comment: @Circeus: Merci de votre réponse. **I.** Que veut dire « un état binaire » ? Je ne saisis pas le sens de « A binary state » ici. **II.** Pourquoi avez-vous écrit « Il n'a pas plu DE la journée » plutôt que « Il n'a pas plu TOUTE la journée » ? Le « DE », peut-il remplacer « TOUTE » ?

Comment: @LaPrevoyance *De* s'emploie avec des expression négatives pour exprimer qu'un fait ne s'est pas produit au cours d'une période. On ne peut pas employer la période directement (à moins que le verbe lui-même ne l'exige, et je ne connaît pas d'exemple qui me vienne à l'esprit) car cela devrait alors être un complément d'objet direct. On peut dire *il n'a pas plus de toute la journée*, mais si cela est plus marqué, le sens de base est le même.

Comment: @Circeus: Je vous remercie toujours. Je crois que vous vouliez dire « On peut dire il n'a pas **PLU (et non pas plus)** de toute la journée, ... » En terminant, puis-je vous expliquer le sens d'« un état binaire » ?

Comment: J'entends que soit il a plu, soit il n'a plus durant la période en question (ce qui peut inclure, sans détails supplémentaires, aussi bien un peu de pluie que des orages diluviens toute la journée), alors qu'avec *il pleuvais* on sous-entend un moment précis (imparfait descriptif combiné à un passé composé) ou qu'il a plu toute ou presque toute la journée (décrivant la journée elle-même).

Comment: @Circeus: Je vous suis reconnaissant. Malheureusement, je suis embrouillé par: « *J'entends que soit il a plu, soit il n'a plus ... diluviens toute la journée)* » ? Deuxième, « *il pleuvais* » sous-entend un moment précisé ? Alors, Mazet a tort car elle maintient que "[The imperfect] does not busy itself with actions"???

Comment: quand je parle d'un "moment précis", il faut prendre le temps de comprendre que "imparfait descriptif combiné à un passé composé" fait référence à des phrases du genre "il pleuvait quand je suis arrivé", auquel cas l'état de "pluvieux" ne s'applique qu'à l'événement qui a été mis au passé composé (et autre descriptif de temps: "lors de mon arrivée" ou "durant la semaine", voire "à ce moment-là" ont le même résultat de "restreindre" la description).

Comment: @Circeus: Je vous reste reconnaissant. Pourriez-vous éclaircir ma première question dans mon commentaire dernier ? Je ne pige pas ce que vous signifiez par:  *J'entends que soit il a plu, soit il n'a plus durant la période en question (ce qui peut inclure, sans détails supplémentaires*.