# What is the verb form in “il a dû tomber” ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, temps-grammatical, infinitif

In the context of someone losing his wallet he says:

> Il a dû tomber dans la rue.

Now what is the sense and form of tense being used?

I understand that *devoir* is conjugated as passé composé. (though *dû* could be used as adjective also). Given that the action is completed in the past, why is not the verb *tomber* conjugated (either in subjonctive since there is speculation, or past/passé composé since the action is complete?

Comment: Perhaps is it the same rule that the second verb is in infinitive e.g. Vous pouvez donner le livre?

Comment: Related: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6249/imparfait-vs-passe-compose-for-devoir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* conjugated. In the infinitive form. Okay, that was a bit tongue in the cheek, but it is true. *Devoir* takes (in this sense) an infinitive proposition, which is often just a verb in the infinitive

> *Je dois **partir***
>   *Je dois **manger***

but can also be a complete propostion

> *Je dois partir en voiture manger à la Tour d'Argent avec Paul Erdős, [qui vient juste de revenir à la vie](http://xkcd.com/599/).*

with everything but the first two words being the argument of *dois*.

Now, if you want to know *why* it is an infinitive, you have trace back to Latin, which for seemingly arbitrary reasons made infinitive (of which they had three: past, present and future) mandatory for object propositions of a certain class of verbs.

It is now the only class of subordinate propositions that has no explicit subordinant (ie neither relative pronoun, nor conjunction…) and it only happens for a fixed set of verbs (see [the corresponding Wikipedia article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition_infinitive#Proposition_infinitive_compl.C3.A9ment_d.27objet))

Comment: Thanks. The literal meaning of my sentence would be "It should have fallen on the road". C'est ça?

Comment: Rather “It must have fallen on the road”. The *should* variant would likely be expressed with “aurait dû”.

Answer (score 1):

"Il a dû tomber" is a French way to say "He probably fell".

"Il a dû payer ses dettes" = He has had to pay his debts.