# Quelle est la difference entre devoir en l'imparfait et devoir dans le passe composé ?

Tags: grammaire, passé-composé, imparfait

Quelle est la difference entre « devoir » en l'imparfait et « devoir » dans le passé composé ?

Je sais que « devoir » dans le passé composé signifie « what had to have happened » ou « what had to be done » en anglais, mais qu'est-ce qu'il signifie en l'imparfait ?

( Et aussi, pouvez-vous parler simplement en français, s'il vous plaît, parce que je ne peux pas comprendre le français trop complexe. Merci ^^ )

Comment: Voir ici: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6249/imparfait-vs-pass%c3%a9-compos%c3%a9-for-devoir. J'espère que l'anglais conviendra. Sinon tu peux demander des traductions pour les réponses.