# Mais B aurait-il de telles connaissances ? / Mais B a-t-il de telles connaissances ?

Tags: conditionnel

Bonjour,

A est un ami de B. D'habitude, la communication entre A et le groupe G n'est pas évidente, mais cette fois, lorsque A entre en contact avec G, la discussion se déroule dans le calme. A se dit alors qu'il se peut que B connaisse des membres du groupe G. Puis, il se demande si c'est possible.

Il pense :

> Mais B **aurait**-il de telles connaissances ?

Est-ce que le conditionnel est correct ici ? D'après ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19362/difference-between-comment-a-t-il-pu-and-comment-aurait-il-pu), je pense que oui, mais je n'arrive pas à m'expliquer son rôle.

Answer (score 1):

A exprime une hypothèse donc le conditionnel est indiqué ici.

*De telles connaissances* étant un peu ambigu, on peut aussi écrire :

– B connaîtrait-il des membres du groupe D ?

ou utiliser l'imparfait comme ceci :

– Et s'il les connaissait ?

Comment: Merci ! _A exprime une hypothèse_ --- Je crois que j'ai trouvé une explication : _On l'emploie ainsi pour exprimer des réserves sur ce que l'on affirme. Cet emploi du conditionnel est courant dans la presse pour présenter une information sous toutes réserves._ [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4148) Est-ce correct ? Donc, _B connaîtrait-il des membres du groupe D ?_ = _Se peut-il que B connaisse des membres...?_ = _Et s'il les connaissait ?_ ?

Comment: Plutôt: *Se **pourrait-il** que B connaisse des membres du groupe D.* car *Se **peut-il** que* exprime seulement une question, pas une hypothèse.

Comment: jlliagre, j'ai du mal à comprendre cette différence. Une question est une hypothèse,non, quoiqu'elle est parfois sous-entendue ? Si j'essaie de traduire ces deux tournures vers le russe, il n'y a presque pas de différence.

Comment: Je comprends. La différence est ténue et il y a une certain recouvrement mais disons qu'une question est en général ouverte et recherche une réponse alors qu'une hypothèse propose une réponse et recherche sa confirmation (c'est vrai) ou son infirmation (c'est faux).

Comment: Ah, merci ! Oui, c'est vrai. J'ai trouvé ici [fil 1](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/en-il-se-peut-il-se-pourrait-que.2771072/) une explication (il se peut / il se pourrait --- may / might), mais ce sera plutôt pour ceux qui connaissent la grammaire anglaise. :) [fil 2](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/il-se-pourrait-peut-que.131327/)

Comment: [Ici](https://wallstreetenglish.fr/fiches-anglais/grammaire/may-might) on explique la différence entre "may" et "might".