# (Peut-être) parce qu’aurait-il des enfants

Tags: conditionnel

Bonjour,

A et B travaillent dans une école. A ouvre la salle que B garde toujours fermée à clé et voit beaucoup de fioles. A se dit que B se passionne pour les réactions chimiques et il pense :

> Pourquoi alors ne pas garder toutes ses fioles et produits chimiques
> chez lui, à la maison ? Cela aurait été plus simple, non ? **Peut-être**
> parce qu’**aurait**-il des enfants et un petit appartement ?

D'après ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45002/mais-b-aurait-il-de-telles-connaissances-mais-b-a-t-il-de-telles-connaissanc), le conditionnel est correct ici. Mais est-il possible d'employer le conditionnel et "peut-être" dans la même phrase ? Est-il préférable de supprimer "peut-être" ?

Answer (score 2):

L'indicatif est attendu car ici, on postule que c'est vrai. D'autre part, l'inversion n'est pas possible après *parce que* :

> Peut-être parce qu’il a des enfants et un petit appartement ?

Le conditionnel est possible comme ceci :

> Aurait-il des enfants et un petit appartement ?

Comment: _on postule que c'est vrai_ À mon avis, on se pose une question, non ? Ce ne serait pas la même chose. _...une question est en général ouverte et recherche une réponse alors qu'une hypothèse propose une réponse et recherche sa confirmation (c'est vrai) ou son infirmation (c'est faux)_ [lien](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45002/mais-b-aurait-il-de-telles-connaissances-mais-b-a-t-il-de-telles-connaissanc) OK, donc je me pose une question. Et la phrase _**Peut-être qu**'aurait-il des enfants et un petit appartement ?_ n'est pas possible, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: Mais ici ma question est aussi une hypothèse, à mon avis. Quoi qu'il en soit, il semble que seules ces deux variantes sont possibles : _Peut-être parce qu’il a des enfants et un petit appartement ?_ et _Aurait-il des enfants et un petit appartement ?_

Comment: *Peut-être qu'aurait-il* n'est pas grammatical car ce qui suit ***peut-être que*** ne peut pas être une question, ce doit être une affirmation ou une négation. Tu pourrais écrire ***peut-être a-t-il des enfants et un petit appartement***.