# Dans un espoir illusoire d’y trouver un bout de papier sur lequel B aurait pu / a pu l'écrire

Tags: conditionnel

Bonjour,

A est devant l'ordinateur de B et il veut le fouiller. Il cherche le mot de passe.

> Je commence à ouvrir les tiroirs, l’un après l’autre, dans un espoir
> illusoire d’y trouver un bout de papier sur lequel B **aurait** **pu**
> l'écrire.
>
> Je commence à ouvrir les tiroirs, l’un après l’autre, dans un espoir
> illusoire d’y trouver un bout de papier sur lequel B **a** **pu**
> l'écrire.

D'après ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45002/mais-b-aurait-il-de-telles-connaissances-mais-b-a-t-il-de-telles-connaissanc), il est possible d'employer le conditionnel passé ici, car il s'agit d'une hypothèse. Est-ce correct ? Le passé composé convient aussi, n'est-ce pas ?

Answer (score 2):

Puisque l'espoir est illusoire, ce papier n'existe pas et le mot de passe n'a pas pu y être écrit. L'indicatif est donc plutôt malvenu.

> Je commence à ouvrir les tiroirs, l’un après l’autre, dans **l'espoir** illusoire d’y trouver un bout de papier sur lequel B **aurait** pu l'écrire.

Ou alors, on sait que B a écrit son mot de passe sur un bout de papier, mais il n'y a aucune chance qu'il se trouve dans l'un des tiroirs :

> Je commence à ouvrir les tiroirs, l’un après l’autre, dans **l'espoir** illusoire d’y trouver **le** bout de papier sur lequel B **a** pu l'écrire.

Le conditionnel est aussi possible.

> Je commence à ouvrir les tiroirs, l’un après l’autre, dans **l'espoir** illusoire d’y trouver **le** bout de papier sur lequel B **aurait** pu l'écrire.

Comment: Je voulais dire qu'il y a très peu de chances que B ait écrit le mot de passe sur une feuille et que ce papier se trouve dans l'un des tiroires. Il y a un peu plus de chances que B l'ait écrit quelque part. A n'en sait rien. Est-ce que je corrige _dans **l**'espoire illusoire_ dans le texte de ma question ou je la laisse telle quelle ?

Comment: Tu peux alors remplacer *illusoire* par *optimiste*, *hasardeux*, *chimérique*, *intrépide* ou quelque chose comme ça, en fonction de l'humeur du personnage. Par ex. : *Je commence à ouvrir les tiroirs, l’un après l’autre, dans l'espoir hasardeux d’y trouver un bout de papier sur lequel B l'aurait écrit.* PS: attention à la terminaison de tiroir et espoir (pas de E final !).

Comment: Oui, mon enfant a programmé la souris pour qu'elle ajoute un "e" si on appuie sur un de ses boutons. :) J'ai changé de mode.

Comment: _Je commence à ouvrir les tiroirs, l’un après l’autre, dans l'espoir hasardeux d’y trouver un bout de papier sur lequel B aurait **pu** l'écrire._ n'est pas mieux, le verbe "pouvoir" indiquant davantage l'incertitude ?

Comment: Oui, c'est mieux, tu peux garder *aurait pu l'écrire*.