# Se pourrait-il / peut-il que les rumeurs soient fondées ?

Tags: conditionnel

Bonjour,

A pense :

> Se **pourrait**-il que les rumeurs qui couraient sur B et ses expériences
> soient fondées ?
>
> Se **peut**-il que les rumeurs qui couraient sur B et ses expériences
> soient fondées ?

Donc, d'après ces fils ([1](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45115/dans-un-espoir-illusoire-d-y-trouver-un-bout-de-papier-sur-lequel-b-aurait-pu)) et ([2](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45002/mais-b-aurait-il-de-telles-connaissances-mais-b-a-t-il-de-telles-connaissanc)), le conditionnel et le présent sont corrects ici, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: Ne poses et reposes-tu pas toujours la même question ? ;-) Les deux phrases sont grammaticalement correctes. J'ai la sensation que dans la première, celui qui s'exprime est plus proche de croire à la véracité de la rumeur alors que dans la deuxième, il s'attend plutôt à ce que la rumeur ne vaille même pas la peine d'être étudiée.

Comment: @jlliagre Le sujet est le même : la différence entre le conditionnel et le présent ou le conditionnel passé et le passé composé, mais le contexte est différent. J'imagine que c'est grâce à divers exemples que l'on intègre une notion. Si après avoir posé deux ou trois questions sur un forum, on comprenait parfaitement une nuance, ce serait formidable...

Answer (score 2):

Je cours le risque de répondre à votre 3eme re-question :)

À la base le conditionnel sous-entend un `Si`

Avant de dire `Se pourrait-il que`  on pense à

> - Si je me penchais sur la question ...
> - Si par hasard ...
> - Si on cherche bien ...

Par contre avec le **Présent** on ne se demande plus si la question vaut la peine d'être étudiée, on y est.

J'espère que le conditionnel passe beaucoup mieux maintenant ?!

Comment: Je l'espère aussi. Merci. :)